# Help in evaluating limit of the given function.

Tags: limits

> Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\cfrac{x^2+5x+3}{x^2+x+2}\right)^x $$

I'm not sure how to evaluate this limit. This is what I've done yet:

$$\begin{align} 
\lim_{x\to \infty} \left\{1 + \left(\cfrac{x^2+5x+3}{x^2+x+2} - 1\right) \right\} ^x\\ 
=\ \lim_{x\to \infty} \left\{1 + \left(\cfrac{4x+1}{x^2+x+2}\right) \right\}^x\end{align}$$

Not sure where to proceed from here. Out of ideas!

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Choose an exponential notation $\left(\frac{x^2+5x+3}{x^2+x+2}\right)^x=exp\left(x\times ln\left(\frac{x^2+5x+3}{x^2+x+2}\right)\right)$

Comment: Can you give a description for what you meant? Did you mean to get it in $e^x$ form? Not sure how :/

Comment: Yes look at up ! ;)

Comment: exp means e^(something) , right?

Comment: Yes this is the exponential function ! ;)

Comment: So, what you did is : $f(x) = e^{\ln(f(x))}$ ?

Comment: What i'm saying is that $a^b=\exp(b*\ln(a))$ :)

Comment: I see what you did there. $$a^b = y \\ b \ln a = \ln y \\ y = e^{b \ln a} $$ 

Right?

Comment: Yes but becareful if a is negative ;)

Comment: What will be different if a is negative? Sorry, but if you can explain a bit...

Comment: $\ln$ is define on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ so if a is negative ...

Comment: Oops. Wait, how did I forget it? :O :O :O Sorry! Didn't concentrate that well over the statement. Feeling dumb. Very sorry! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2+5x+3}{x^2+x+2}\right)^x&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{x^2+x+2}{4x+1}}\right)^{\frac{x^2+x+2}{4x+1}\cdot\frac{x(4x+1)}{x^2+x+2}}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{x^2+x+2}{4x+1}}\right)^{\frac{x^2+x+2}{4x+1}}\right)^{\frac{4+\frac 1x}{1+\frac 1x+\frac{2}{x^2}}}\\&=e^4\end{align}$$
Here, note that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2+x+2}{4x+1}=+\infty$ and that $\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 1y\right)^y=e$.

Comment: I see! I see! I finally see! :D Got it Captain! :) Thanks a lot @mathlove . Awesome...! :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what machinery you have at your disposal. Can you use the continuity of functions? The rules of de l'Hospital? Logarithms?

Ultimately, what you have to come to grips with here is that in the limit you have the indeterminate form $1^\infty$, which one normally reduces to one of the simpler forms $0\over0$ or $\infty\over\infty$ before doing the evaluation of the limit.

Comment: Well, there is no boundation as such which method is to be used. Any method can be used as far as this question is considered. Do you have any clue to do this by using LH rule?

Comment: It won't be pretty, but your expression is essentially $[f_1(x)/f_2(x)]^x$, which is the same as $e^{x*ln(f_1(x)}/e^{x*ln(f_2(x)}$. You can take the derivatives in the numerator and denominator and simplify.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot for your help @user3697176 ! Glad you helped.